# Error installing homebrew on mac (curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com)

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to following instructions on homebrew homepage but the following

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

returns the following error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably a network issue on your end. `curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install` works fine for me.

Answer (score 20):

If you happen to be behind a proxy, You might need a way out, to exit

```
export http_proxy=http://YOURPROXY:PORT export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

For some other users, setting back their github https and https-proxy to default works sometimes as well.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Comment: export http_proxy=http://YOURPROXY:PORT export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy worked for me as per your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

I have resolved this by adding a new name server into network configuration.

Click on "System Preferences" then "Network", "Advanced" , "DNS", "+" and enter IP of the new name server, a good public name server is "8.8.8.8" .

Answer (score 6):

As others noted, the problem is a proxy blocking access to the download. The "non-hack" solution is...

1. Disconnect from your personal/company's VPN
2. Rerun the homebrew installation script

Currently...

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are most probably behind a proxy. Consider running curl command with -k parameter:

> -k, --insecure
>          (SSL)  This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All
>          SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate  bundle  installed  by
>          default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k, --insecure is used.
>
> See this online resource for further details:
>   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Check also [Homebrew docs](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#ignoring-ssl-certificate-errors-not-recommended) where they talk about this.

Answer (score 3):

Tried everything,

Finally installing Cloudflare on the machine sorted out the issue.

Follow this: https://developers.cloudflare.com/warp-client/get-started/linux/

Comment: Thank you travis, This actually works for me on MacOS as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to solve this issue by cloning the repository to local directory and executing install.sh file manually.

Steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/install.git
/bin/bash install/install.sh
```

Thank me later ;)

Answer (score 1):

If non of the above solutions worked and you can't ping https://github.com/ or any other websites with your terminal ,it is because of an application that monitors and controls the access of network , so make sure that your terminal is not blocked from accessing the network by any Firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

It gave an error on the first attempt. However, it was installed on second attempt. The solution is to retry attempting the call.

Answer (score 1):

Setting proxy with Username, password and port number worked for me

```
 export http_proxy=http://<MacUser>:<MacPass><proxy server>:<ProxyPort>
 export https_proxy=http_proxy
```

After that simply execute

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: How can we find the port number here ?

Comment: You need to ask your local admin which port they use for proxy

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue recently and I was not sure what is my proxy address and port as nothing was selected under the connection proxy.

Followed this :

Click on "System Preferences" then "Network", on selected connection click "Advanced", then click "proxy"

I simply appended ', *raw.githubusercontent.com*' in text area given for "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains:"
It now looks like:
*.local, 169.254/16, *raw.githubusercontent.com*

Now, retry `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

literally just restart the machine. Worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same issue while trying to install home-brew on my Mac M1

Did the following, issue resolved.

Paste this in the terminal and hit enter.

export http_proxy=http://YOURPROXY:PORT export ALL_PROXY=$http_proxy

Now paste the home-brew installation cmd in terminal

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was running Gananche Blockchain simulation on my machine, once I quit that application I was able to use Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

as Marian mentioned above, I resolved it by doing this in ubuntu:

```
sudo su
vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment existing nameserver and add this:

```
#nameserver 172.22.112.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.4.4.8
```

it resolved things for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that the firewall isn't blocking was helpful for me