# Bought a new Mac today, but I had been crashed by the terminal configuration...help me

Tags: bash, shell, proxy, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I bought a new MacBook today,but I had been crashed by the terminal configuration...
The terminal always shows errors when i tried to change the terminal shell.
`wget: command not found` or`curl: command not found`.

Then, I tried to use iTerm2 application.It shows `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.github.com`.I took into account the possible reasons for the firewall due to China,so I went on looking up the information...

Now, I followed the [introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761799/error-installing-homebrew-on-mac-curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-raw-githubus) and modify setting ,it shows `curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted`...
OMG!Who can help me ...please

Answer (score 0):

It looks your `$PATH` is messed up. Check by running `echo $PATH` in the terminal. Should like the following:

`$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

If not, then check the `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_profile`.

On the issue of not being able to resolve the domain, its likely due to the firewall/proxy in your environment.

Comment: I'm so sorry for reply now...yeah,your answer is correct answer.The issue was really due to the firewall.It was ok when I opened the shadowsockX . Thank you ~